# Compute $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \dfrac{\sqrt{n}\sin x}{1+n\sqrt{x}}dx$ using the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \dfrac{\sqrt{n}\sin x}{1+n\sqrt{x}}\,dx$$

My work:

I noticed that the integrand converges pointwise to zero.  If I fix $x$, divide through by $n$ and then take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$, the result is $\frac{0}{1+\sqrt{x}} = 0$

I noticed that my function is dominated on $[0, 1]$ by $sinx$.

Thus by the LDCT, the integral is the same as the integral $\int_0^1 0 dx = 0$

Is this okay?

Comment: Are you sure that the function is dominated by $\sin x?$

Comment: is this plot opening your eyes?
Plot[{100 sin(x)/(1+10000 Sqrt[x]),100 sin(x)/(10000 Sqrt[x])},{x,0,1}]

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say it is dominated by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: yes, of course.

Comment: @Greg Are you sure? This is odd, I was convinced that $$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=\left.2\sqrt{x}\right|_0^1=2$$ was finite. Please explain.

Comment: $$0\leqslant\frac{\sqrt{n}\sin x}{1+n\sqrt{x}}\leqslant\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{x}}=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\frac1{\sqrt{x}}\implies0\leqslant\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{n}\sin x}{1+n\sqrt{x}}\,dx\leqslant\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\left.2\sqrt{x}\right|_0^1=\frac2{\sqrt{n}}\to0$$

Comment: @Greg No problem. The irony here is that two users saw fit to show their enthusiasm for your first comment by upvoting it, in less than one hour...

Comment: We can compute it using your favourite horseshoe.

Answer (score 4):

Note that for $n\ge 1$, $n\ge \sqrt n$.  Therefore, we have

$$\left|\frac{\sqrt n \,\sin(x)}{1+n\sqrt x}\right| \le \frac{\sqrt n \, |\sin(x)|}{\sqrt n\, \sqrt x}=\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt x}$$

for $0\le x\le 1$.

Since $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt x}\,dx<\infty$, the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt n \,\sin(x)}{1+n\sqrt x}\,dx  =\int_0^1 \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt n\,\sin(x)}{1+n\sqrt x} \, dx=0$$

as was to be shown.

---

Note that we need not rely on the Dominated Convergence Theorem to evaluate the limit.  Simply note that

$$\left|\frac{\sqrt{n}\sin(x)}{1+n\sqrt{x}}\right|\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{nx}}$$

Inasmuch as $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt {n x}}\,dx=\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\to 0$, then by the squeeze theorem, we establish the coveted limit.